# Extending the IIdentity Interface in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a question regarding IIdentity in ASP.NET Core.

I will note that I am not using ASP.NET Core Identity, but I am using the tooling available in asp.net core authentication and authorization (and interfaces/classes in System.Security.[...]).

Here is what a standard implementation of the IIdentity Interface looks like:

```cs
public class myIdentity : IIdentity
{
    public string AuthenticationType { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsInRole(string Role)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Where the property `Name` is described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.iidentity?view=net-5.0) as

> Name: Gets the name of the current user.

I kept wondering why they don't include a property to represent generic basic info about the user. `Name` is useful, but I also have the need to include other basic information about the user. For example, in later middleware, it would be nice to have something like the primary key for my user table available right there in `HttpContext.User.Identity` to pass to some pretty involved Stored Procedures.

I thought about using `HttpContext.Items`, but I would prefer to keep all user-centric properties in one place (IIdentity or similar).

Is there a method of extending IIdentity for this use case? Would I just extend the interface?

I saw some other questions out there that beat around the bush, some with rather complex examples (custom IIdentities and IPrincipals and more), but figured this question could bring simplicity and clarity to a very basic example.

Comment: I think the extensibility point designed into `User` (a `ClaimsPrincipal`) is the property `Claims`. Extra info should be added as claims. You then can find a claim by its type. Of course, when it comes to general (dynamic), we cannot simply have beautiful style like strongly-typed (but static) model.

Comment: I believe it's possible to extend your `ClaimsPrincipal` by defining a class inheriting from `ClaimsPrincipal` but the `User` property is just a `ClaimsPrincipal`, so you need some extension method (on the `HttpContext`) to cast it to the designed type (that you know for sure is the actual type of `User`). That way you may need to override how `User` is set on `HttpContext`, which is always set to an instance of `ClaimsPrincipal` (not your custom extended class).

Comment: So a claim is meant to be anything (and everything) that makes up an identity, including generic information like name or identifiers or, for example, authorization roles as well? For some reason I painted claims something strictly related to authorization.

Comment: Of course it's part of user's data and actually everything about user can be used for authorization. But not all must be used for authorization (even sometimes not even one claim is used). You should however not include large data in the claims set. Otherwise you need to deal with the problem of large data set in the authentication cookies.

Comment: I thought it would be convenient to have a my user table primary key in httpcontext for easy access (in subsequent code after authorization has taken place). I guess storing that key in a claim wouldn’t make much sense semantically.

Comment: I missed that there... you’re saying that some claims don’t have to be used for authorization per-say?

Comment: to me that makes sense, because that's kind of info that can identify a user (user id), it's much like user name. Suppose some sub-system of your app requires authorizing against your user id (instead of other data), then you just have it for each user. As I said, not all claims ***must*** be used for authorization. They're usually used for authorization but I believe they can be used for some other purpose as long as it is convenient. Generally you may have unbound info about a user, so we may need a different general solution which deals better with large data.

Comment: Okay that clears a lot up for me. Thanks for the conversation!

Comment: for large claims set, you can implement an `ITicketStore` which will load the full info (in claims) via the session id and only session id is set in the cookies (not all which will be impossible when the data is large).

Comment: I see. I don’t have an incredibly large claims set as it is... even after I put some more user data I want as claims in there.

Comment: I’m implementing custom authentication with an opaque token, so when a request comes, I’m hitting the db to get roles associated with the user (authenticated by the token) which I then generate my claims set from.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks again for the extended discussion. How many claims do you think is too many? Right now, including basic user info claims and role claims, I am going to end up with ~25 claims within my ClaimsPrincipal.

Comment: I think it depends on the data size rather than the number of claims. As long as it's allowed (under the max headers size defined by the server), it's acceptable. Kestrel has the default limit of  headers size by `32KB`. The trade-off of large data sent back & forth between clients and server is of course some decrease in performance (more bandwidth required, more delay, ...). When it comes to performance, you of course may have to test it to know if it's still good. I personally would of course avoid large round-trip data. But for convenience, you can take the tradeoffs